# Scroll screen in XNA - Easing math (flick gesture)

Tags: math, xna, gesture, easing

I've been trying back and forth, but I can't figure out the math on how to scroll my view (or rather offset all objects) when using the flick gesture. I would like the scrolling to have some kind of ease-out.

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, bool otherScreenHasFocus, bool coveredByOtherScreen)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        //Some math to change 'matrixOffsetY'
        //I use 'matrixOffsetY' to offset my objects in Draw()

        base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, coveredByOtherScreen);
    }
```

Here's the gesture event

```
    public override void HandleInput(InputState input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

            switch (gesture.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.Flick:
                    {
                        //Set a variable with some math? Using:
                        //gesture.Delta

                        //gesture.Delta gives us pixels/sec
                        break;
                    }
                default: return;
            }
        }
    }
```

This shouldn't be that hard, but I have a brain-freeze :) Please help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "lerp" (linear interpolate) between two values to gradually get closer (starting fast, ending slowly).

I assume you're scrolling in 2D. So the position is a Vector2.

Try something like this:

```
position; //current position of the object.
targetPosition; //set by scrolling, position should gradually come close to this
float weigth; //how much the weight is of the targetPosition compared to the position
//practically this means how fast position approaches targetPosition. 
//First try values between 0 and 1, for example 0.8f for starters.
public void Scroll(Vector2 ammount)
{
   //We assume scrolling the scrollbar 1 pixel down, means the object should go 1 pixel up.
   //So the targetPosition should move the same ammount opposite.
   //If you don't want scrolling to correspond 1:1, you can multiply ammount by a float.
   targetPosition -= ammount;   
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //..
    //Executed every update, position closes in on targetPosition pretty fast.     
    position = Vector2.Lerp(position, targetPosition, weigth);

    //Because we Lerp position will only get extremely close to targetPosition. Never exactly at it.
    //most of the time this is good enough, if this isnt use the following code

    float omega = 0.05f; // the minimum dinstance between position and targetPosition before we clamp
    if(Vector2.Distance(position, targetPosition) < omega)
    {
        position = targetPosition;
    }
    //..
}

public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //..
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
    //..
}
```

Comment: Wow. Works flawlessly and better than I expected! Thanks.

Comment: Hey Frexuz, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean by "ease out" that it gradually does what it's suppose to do(which I'm not quite clear on(I don't know much about touchpanels and gestures).

There are several ways to do this. You could take a physical approach and use newton's law and simply solve the differential equation.

The way I generally do things like this(such as a gradual stop when scrolling a window with the mouse), is to simply reduce the speed gradually using some function with parameters that I can modify to get the feel I want.

In your case, I've I get what you trying to do, you simply want to update the position based on the velocity.

Suppose your doing it horizontally(in generally you'll do it for 2D),

X_new = X_old + velocity*dt
velocity = max(0, velocity*0.95 - 0.2)

What this does is gradually move the x coordinate(X_old becomes X_new each time through the loop(which you'll usually do in a thread)) so that instead of stopping completely it continues to move until velocity has reached zero. I use a simple pow function to gradually reduce it but you can come up with any type of function.

You can also actually take into account the distance of the pointer to the edge. I do this in one of my programs so that when the mouse cursor is moved off the edge the speed it scrolls depends on how far(so if you wanna scroll a little you move a little and a lot you move a lot).

Be aware you'll have to handle this in a thread probably because it is something that continues to happen. You could also compute the acceleration and use the simple physics to compute the position based on it. x = x0 + x'*t + 1/2*x''*t^2 type of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, if it's XNA, Shawn has probably solved your problem already. In a couple of posts he explains transitions using [Lerp, SmoothStep and other math operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/05/03/transitions-part-one-the-importance-of-curves.aspx), and a [physics based approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/05/13/transitions-part-two-let-s-get-physical.aspx). The examples use the Game State Management project, but the ideas can be used anywhere.

And, by the way, you might want to consider not moving all the objects around relative to the camera. You can store a vector2 or vector3 cameraOffset somewhere and use a transformMatrix in SpriteBatch.Begin. Of course, this is most useful if you use one or two spritebatch cycles to paint all your world objects.

Comment: Actually I did this before, but drawing so many objects at the same time, gave me about 3 fps since my "canvas" was 5000px high. Since the Y of the objects doesn't change, I couldn't figure out how to draw only the visible objects.

Comment: The same way you select what to paint if the camera is static. Instead of painting anything inside a rectangle (0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight) plus padding, the rectangle would be (cameraPos.X - halfScreenWidth, cameraPos.Y - halfScreenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight) plus padding. You can even keep a rectangle attached to the camera and check for intersections. Everything intersecting its viewRect at its Z is painted. Adding partitions to the game area would make it even faster.